# Matplotlib plots straight line for Exp[x]

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, differential-equations

It plots correctly if I delete the function problem2, I need to print both of them, but whenever that's done, Exp[x] is printed as a straight line. I've printed f(x) to see is it getting the right values or not and it does get the right values. Problem2 is a differential eqn. I have solved it using odeint, f(x) is the answer of Problem2 given in the book, I want to plot both of them together to see whether the solution given by python is correct or not. Problem20 = 10 is an initial value I have taken randomly ( can it be also a source of error, I failed to see how if so).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as sciint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def problem2(y, x):
    return x + x * y


def f(x):
    return np.exp(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
    problem20 = 10
    sol = sciint.odeint(problem2, problem20, x)
    plt.plot(x, sol, label="Calculated")
    print(f(x))
    plt.plot(x, f(x), label="Given in book")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't do integrals for pleasure so I can't explain why, but when I try to plot your code with `x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)` I clearly see that your equations are not even close to be equal.

Comment: `y' = x*(1+y)` integrates to `y(x)+1 = (y0+1)*exp(x^2/2)`, which is much more rapidly growing than `exp(x)`. Thus in a scaled plot, the graph of `f` is much compressed vertically, looking mostly like a horizontal line.

Comment: While the reason title "non-reproducible or typo" for my close vote does not exactly fit, the problem here is the wrong exact solution, so either something wrong with the source of the task or the interpretation of it. This is not a programming problem, thus the answer is not useful for future readers on a programming-related forum.